# What is this? getproccount

Tags: c, go, bit-manipulation

What is going on in this code?  From the name and the context it's finding the number of cores on the machine, but how does it work?  What's all that bit fiddling for?

```
static int32
getproccount(void)
{
        uintptr buf[16], t;
        int32 r, cnt, i;

        cnt = 0;
        r = runtime·sched_getaffinity(0, sizeof(buf), buf);
        if(r > 0)
        for(i = 0; i < r/sizeof(buf[0]); i++) {
                t = buf[i];
                t = t - ((t >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555ULL);
                t = (t & 0x3333333333333333ULL) + ((t >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333ULL);
                cnt += (int32)((((t + (t >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL) * 0x101010101010101ULL) >> 56);
        }

        return cnt ? cnt : 1;
}
```

Note: ignore the `·` in `runtime·sched_getaffinity`, think of that line as just an arbitrary library/system call that does what the name and arguments imply. (In this case this specific call comes from [the *old* pre-Go1.4 runtime](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.4/src/runtime/os_linux.c) written in a slight variation of C that deals with `·`).

Comment: Check out http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html . Search for "Counting bits set, in parallel"

Comment: All that bit manipulation is a fairly common implementation of the `popcount` function.... it's counting how many bits are set in the buffer.

Comment: Wow. That code should really have a comment describing what it's doing.

Comment: @Jongware the project Go used its own C compiler which supports this.

Comment: rollback note: I don't think this should be tagged Go. It's C code, it just happens to be in the old Go run-time (which has since been rewritten in Go btw). The only non-standard C thing is the use of `·` in an identifier (the Go ABI uses that).

Comment: @Ishay Peled Ishay Peled it's one thing to re-add the Go tag, but you removed the C tag as well!!. The *only* non-standard C thing, the use of a `·` in an identifier, is completely irrelevant to this question. If the function happened to come from SillyOS and happened to contain an irrelevant call to SillyOSSpecificButObviousSyscall before the asked about bit fiddling, would that then require a useless SillyOS tag on the question? There is nothing in this question that anyone following or searching the `tag:go` tag would care about but the lots that those following/searching tag:c would.

Comment: Flagged, let someone else decide.

Comment: So **rename** that one function call to something less conspicuous, as it seems **not relevant** and only distracts from the actual question. Renaming it removes the 'need' (or 'want') for a Go compatible compiler, and thus, logically, the Go tag. What remains is a clear C-only question.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop runs over as many elements that get filled into the `buf` array. For each of those elements, it calculates the number of bits that are set in that element (the bit fiddling with `t` does just that) and that is added into `cnt`. At the end `cnt` is returned (or 1 if `cnt` is 0).

### Explanation for the bit fiddling:

**Bit fiddling line 1**

The line `t = t - ((t >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555ULL);` basically groups off the bits of `t` into 2 bits and replaces each group with the count of the number of set bits in that group. This works like follows:

Consider `t = ... w x y z` where w,x,y,z are individual bits. Then

```
t                 = ... w x y z
t>>1              = ..... w x y
t>>1 & 0x...55ULL = ... 0 w 0 y
```

From above, it is clear to see why the grouping happens into 2 bits (for example, y and z get grouped together here). Now `t - ((t >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555ULL)` will have each group of 2 bits `y z` transformed to `(y-z)`. Using a table of the 4 possibilities (00, 01, 10, 11), we see that the answers are (00, 01, 01, 10) which matches with the number of bits set in that group of 2 bits.

**Bit fiddling line 2**

Moving on to the next bit fiddling line `t = (t & 0x3333333333333333ULL) + ((t >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333ULL);`, we can see that it is adding up adjacent groups of 2 in groups of 2.

`t & 0x..33ULL` takes the rightmost 2 bits of each group of 4 bits.
`(t>>2) & 0x..33ULL` takes the leftmost 2 bits of each group of 4 bits and shifts them right by 2.
Since these two groups of 2 bits were the number of bits set in the original number, it has added up the number of bits set in every group of 4 bits. (i.e. now, each group of 4 bits has the number of bits that were set originally in those positions)

**Bit fiddling line 3**

As for the last bit fiddling line `cnt += (int32)((((t + (t >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL) * 0x101010101010101ULL) >> 56);`, we can break it down into a few parts for easier understanding.

```
(int32)(
  (
    (
      (
        t + (t >> 4)
      ) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL
    ) * 0x101010101010101ULL
  ) >> 56
)
```

Currently, each group of 4 bits stores the number of bits that were set originally in the number. Shifting the number over by 4 and adding would add all adjecent groups together. `&`ing with `0x..0F0FULL` picks out the right 4 bits of each group of 8 bits. Hence, at the end of `(t + (t >> 4)) & 0x...0F0FULL`, there are groups of 8 bits which contain the number of bits that were there in those locations in the original number. Let's just call this number `s = (t + (t >> 4)) & 0x...0F0FULL` for simplicity.

We now have to do `(s * 0x...0101ULL) >> 56`. Notice that `t` and thus `s` are 64 bits in size. This means that there are 8 groups of 8 bits. By simple multiplication with `0x...0101ULL` (which is just the rightmost bit turned on for each group), the leftmost group will now be the sum of all the groups. By shifting right by 56 (i.e. `(64 - 8)`), we move this leftmost group into the rigthmost position. This means that the rightmost group of 8 bits now has the sum of all the groups of `s`. But `s`'s groups were the number of set bits in those locations in the number, therefore, after the `>>56` operation, we have the total number of set bits in the original number. The `(int32)` is just typecasting to a lower size datatype (which is actually enough to store this number.

Note: A bit being set means that the bit is equal to 1.